# MS Access - Run Macro in Query - Time Conversion

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, datetime, time

I am trying to select data from various tables. The only problem is, that in one table, the time is in the format "positive minutes from midnight" whereas all other tables store time in some standard TIME format. This prevents me from JOINING those.
Apart from that, adding another column to the other tables is impossible.
So my solution would be the following:

**1. Get both date and minutes from midnight from table**

**2. Create Time/Date Object (using VB i guess)**

**3. Add MINUTES to the Time/Date Object**

But I have no idea where or how I could do that. I will have to create a report, right?
I would be glad if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for VBA here. You can create a query in which you convert the time to the proper format. Then you join the second table to this query.

You can convert the time with this formula in the query builder:

```
[Date]+[MinFromMidnight]/1440
```

Comment: I was 25 secs earlier)))) hell, SO makes me think really fast)

Comment: My +1 for the beauty of syntax pal)

Comment: @PeterL.: If you wouldn't already be 500pt ahead, I'd say we're having a fun race here! ;-)

Comment: @PeterAlbert I like such race the best - it boosts performance and brings fun)

Comment: If only it would not affect my real-world performance! ;-) Has boncodigo remarked in his profile - SO can get quite addictive - and is a good source for procrastination...

Comment: @PeterAlbert don't worry buddy, I got my 2k+ for just a month simply because I have no urgent projects under testing these days, and I may spent hours on SO seeking for new Qs - still improving my skills for later)

Answer (score 1):

"positive minutes from midnight" - for this use `X / 60 / 24`. The obtained value may be added to date.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view (select query) of the first table, that includes the time as a computed field. Then you could join the view to the rest of your tables.